# R: Concatenated values in column B based on values in column A

Tags: r

**QUESTION:** Using R, how would you create values in column B prefixed with a constant "1" + n 0's where n is the value in each row in column A?

```
    #R CODE EXAMPLE
    df <- as.data.frame(1:3);colnames(df)[1] <- "A";
    print(df);
    # A
    # 1
    # 2
    # 3
    preFixedValue <- 1; repeatedValue <- 0;
    #pseudo code: create values in column B with n 0's prefixed with 1 
    df <- cbind(df,paste(rep(c(preFixedValue,repeatedValue), times = c(1,df[1:nrow(df),])),collapse = ""));
    #expected/desired result
    #  A B
    #  1 10
    #  2 100
    #  3 1000
```

**USE CASE:** Real data contains hundreds of rows in column A with random integers, not just three sequential int's as shown in the code above.

Below is an example using Excel to demonstrate what I want to do in R.

[image: Below is an example using Excel to demonstrate what I want to do in R.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For maximum flexibility, i.e. total freedom of choosing prefixed and repeated values as single values or vectors, and for simplicity of the syntax (one single line):

```
library(stringr)
df$B <- str_pad(preFixedValue, width = df$A, pad = repeatedValue, side = c("right"))
```

Answer (score 4):

The rowwise() function in dplyr lets you make variables from column values in each row.

```
require(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(A = 1:3, B = NA)
preFixedValue <- 1; repeatedValue <- 0;

df <- df %>%
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(B = as.numeric(paste0(c(preFixedValue, rep(repeatedValue, A)), collapse = "")))
```

Answer (score 1):

Would something like this work?

```
B<-10^(df$A)
df<-cbind(df,B)
```